# Remover Padding ImageButton Android

Tags: android

[image: Remove Padding]

Utilizo ImageButton para dar un efecto de seleccion, pero no puedo hacer que la imagen este pegada al borde inferior, alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Este es el layout.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    style="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="-15dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso no definas padding negativo, define el padding inferior con `0dp`, para que permita posicionarse la imagen correctamente en el inferior.

```
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
```

y ya que la altura de tu `ImageButton` es `110dp`, simplemente resta la altura de tu imagen a esta altura para obtener el padding superior, por ejemplo:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    style="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho! Ya había implementado otras cosas para replicar el efecto Ripple y colocarle un Corner al button.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle más al paddingTop y el paddingBotton dejarlo en cero por ejemplo:

android:paddingBottom="0dp"

android:paddingTop="90dp"

Saludos